# Add rows to a df in R that are missing and fill with NA using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, na, rbind

So I have a df like this

```
ID  store        price
1   Walmart      1.00
2   WholeFoods   2.33
3   Footlocker   2.55
4   Denny's      1.09
5   Walgreens    .99
6   CVS          7.00
```

After some manipulation it becomes

```
ID  store        price  varA   varB  varC
2   WholeFoods   2.33   D      56    A
3   Footlocker   2.55   TT     302   B
6   CVS          7.00   A      122   C
```

My goal is I want a DF with all the ID's in it in this new df, just with NA on those new columns, so basically.

```
ID  store        price  varA   varB  varC
1   Walmart      1.00   NA     NA    NA
2   WholeFoods   2.33   D      56    A
3   Footlocker   2.55   TT     302   B
4   Denny's      1.09   NA     NA    NA
5   Walgreens    .99    NA     NA    NA
6   CVS          7.00   A      122   C
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dplyr` or mabye better `base R` solution.

### dplyr

In your particular case it can be done using [`full_join()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join.html) from `dplyr` package:

```
a <- read.table(header = T, text = "
ID  store        price
1   Walmart      1.00
2   WholeFoods   2.33
3   Footlocker   2.55
4   Denny's      1.09
5   Walgreens    .99
6   CVS          7.00
")

b <- read.table(header = T, text = "
ID  store        price  varA   varB  varC
2   WholeFoods   2.33   D      56    A
3   Footlocker   2.55   TT     302   B
6   CVS          7.00   A      122   C
")

full_join(a, b)
```

Result:

```
  ID      store price varA varB varC
1  1    Walmart  1.00 <NA>   NA <NA>
2  2 WholeFoods  2.33    D   56    A
3  3 Footlocker  2.55   TT  302    B
4  4    Denny's  1.09 <NA>   NA <NA>
5  5  Walgreens  0.99 <NA>   NA <NA>
6  6        CVS  7.00    A  122    C
```

### Base R solution

It can be easily done with `base R`'s [`merge()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/merge.html) function:

```
merge(a, b, all = TRUE)
#  ID      store price varA varB varC
#1  1    Walmart  1.00 <NA>   NA <NA>
#2  2 WholeFoods  2.33    D   56    A
#3  3 Footlocker  2.55   TT  302    B
#4  4    Denny's  1.09 <NA>   NA <NA>
#5  5  Walgreens  0.99 <NA>   NA <NA>
#6  6        CVS  7.00    A  122    C
```

which is even faster that `dplyr`:

```
Unit: milliseconds
                 expr    min       lq      mean   median       uq     max neval
 merge(a, b, all = T) 1.3881  2.42335  3.259999  2.96615  4.01390  8.9954   100
      full_join(a, b) 6.2017 10.17300 12.653397 12.36170 14.46095 34.0763   100
```

Answer (score 0):

You can left join the second data frame with the first data frame:

```
dplyr::left_join(df1, df2)
```

This will produce the expected output:

```
Joining, by = c("ID", "store", "price")
  ID      store price varA varB varC
1  1    Walmart  1.00 <NA>   NA <NA>
2  2 WholeFoods  2.33    D   56    A
3  3 Footlocker  2.55   TT  302    B
4  4    Denny's  1.09 <NA>   NA <NA>
5  5  Walgreens  0.99 <NA>   NA <NA>
6  6        CVS  7.00    A  122    C
```